# Auto line break in cell every X characters

Tags: excel, text, cell, line-breaks

I have a huge cell containing text which is without line breaks. Once I need to copy&paste it I use online auto line breaker [tool](http://textmechanic.com/Add-Remove-Line-Breaks.html) which makes new break lines every X characters.

I'm looking for solution how to make this work in Excel.

Comment: If you want to have word wrapping, I believe you'll need to write some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be practical, depending upon how often required and how many cells are to be split by line at a time, but most things possible with VBA are also *possible* without, even if impractical.

Assuming your text is in B1 and the requisite character limit in A1. In C1:

```
=MID($B1,1+$A1*(COLUMN()-3),$A1)
```

copied across to D1. In C2 `=C1`, in D2:

```
=C2&CHAR(10)&D1
```

then copy D1:D2 across until first blank shows up in Row1 (assumes you won't have a multitude of consecutive space 'characters').

The result should be below the last non-blank cell in Row1.

[image: SO33432188 example]